# Error 1004 En tiempo de ejecución

Tags: excel, vb

Buen día.

Aclaro que no soy un experto ni mucho menos en el uso de Excel y hay algunas cosas que aún no entiendo. El punto es que lo que quiero es que cuando apriete el botón de Agregar. Pueda agregar cierto formato de la fila anterior. Automaticamente.

Aúnado a ésto tiene en el evento de cambio de pagina que cuando detecte un cambio en una celda, se borre todo lo que tenga en las posteriores dos celdas.

La funcionalidad me lo hace de manera correcta. El problema es que cuando aprieto el botón de agregar, [siempre me manda un mensaje de error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOIzg.png) (Aunque si me hace bien su funcionalidad). Entonces quisiera saber el por qué me manda el error, y si habría alguna forma de solucionar ese mensaje que me [redirecciona al evento que borra las dos celdas que ocupo borrar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7xKB.png) (que si me lo hace).

A continuación dejo el codigo de lo que les comento.

De antemano muchas gracias.

```
Dim NroFila As Integer
Dim NroColumna As Integer
Dim NroConse As Integer

Private Sub CmdAgrega_Click()
    NroColumna = 0
    NroConse = 1
    nrovalor = 0
    NroFila = 17

    While Not Range("A" & NroFila).Value = ""
        NroFila = NroFila + 1
        NroConse = NroConse + 1
    Wend

    NroColumna = ActiveCell.Column
    'NroConse = Range("A" & NroFila).Value
    nrovalor = NroConse

    While nrovalor <> 0
        'NroFila = NroFila + 1
        nrovalor = Range("A" & NroFila).Value
        ActiveCell.Activate

        If nrovalor <> 0 Then
            NroConse = nrovalor
        End If

    Wend

    Rows(NroFila).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'Range("A" & NroFila).Value = NroConse + 1

End Sub




Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
   Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
   Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
 End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias, resolví mi duda anexándole al evento lo siguiente:

**Al inicio**
Application.EnableEvents = False

**Al final**
Application.EnableEvents = True

De forma que quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Sub CmdAgrega_Click()
Application.EnableEvents = False
    NroColumna = 0
    NroConse = 1
    nrovalor = 0
    NroFila = 20

    While Not Range("A" & NroFila).Value = ""
        NroFila = NroFila + 1
        NroConse = NroConse + 1
    Wend

    NroColumna = ActiveCell.Column
    'NroConse = Range("A" & NroFila).Value
    nrovalor = NroConse

    While nrovalor <> 0
        'NroFila = NroFila + 1
        nrovalor = Range("A" & NroFila).Value
        ActiveCell.Activate

        If nrovalor <> 0 Then
            NroConse = nrovalor
        End If

    Wend

    Rows(NroFila).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'Range("A" & NroFila).Value = NroConse + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

**Saludos y muchas gracias.**

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es porque la referencia a la que estabas apuntando se ha desplazado hacia abajo, por lo tanto el rango que está comparando es ambiguo.

Hice este cambio en el procedimiento que tienes en el Worksheet en vez de apuntar por completo a la columna H apunto al valor que tenía previo al desplazamiento del evento `CmdAgrega_Click`

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H" & Target.Row + 1)) Is Nothing Then
   Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
   Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, abajo ya describí la duda resuelta.